# Is $\mathbb{R}$ with the cofinite topology compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

To begin with I already know any set with the cofinite topology is compact, but I am looking for a proof specific to $\mathbb{R}_{\mathcal{FC}}$. My attempt to a proof is right here:

Recall that any $A \subset \mathbb{R}_{\mathcal{FC}}$ is open if $A=\varnothing$ or $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ is finite and as a result every closed $X\subset\mathbb{R}_{\mathcal{FC}}$ is finite or $X=\mathbb{R}$ making $\mathbb{R}$ closed. By definition $\mathbb{R}$ is also open, so $\mathbb{R}$ is clopen. Recall that also $\varnothing$ is open by definition but also closed as it is finite, so it too is the only other clopen set.

If every closed set is finite in $\mathbb{R}_{\mathcal{FC}}$ then every open set must be infinite. As a result every possible open cover must the union of infinite sets in which case a subcover could be expressed as a finite union of infinite sets, so $\mathbb{R}_{\mathcal{FC}}$ is compact.

Comment: upvote mine if it suits you as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't trust this sentence.

> As a result every possible open cover must the union of infinite sets in which case a subcover could be expressed as a finite union of infinite sets, so $\Bbb{R}_\mathcal{FC}$ is compact.

More convincing would be to pick any nonempty member of the cover, $U$, label the points in its finite complement, $x_1, \dots, x_n$, then observe that each such point is covered by at least one member of the cover, $U(x_i)$.  Then take as a finite cover $\{U, U(x_1), \dots, U(x_n)\}$.

Comment: I didn't trust that sentence either which is why I posted this lol. So youre taking a member of the cover and saying that this member can be divided into subsets which collectively contains these finite points and also covers $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: sorry i meant "and as a result covers $\mathbb{R}$"

Comment: If you have a cover of $\Bbb{R}$, each nonempty member of the cover covers all but finitely many points.  Each of those uncovered points is covered by at least one member of the cover, so throw in that member.  This gives a finite cover of $\Bbb{R}$ as a subcover of the initial cover.

Comment: could you upvote mine, if it works as well.

Answer (score 1):

To see why your argument fails, consider the cocountable topology on $\mathbb R$ where a non-empty set is open iff its complement is *countable.*

Since every non-empty open set is the complement of a countable set, it is uncountable, and therefore infinite. As a result, again every possible open cover must be the union of infinite sets (and possibly the empty set, but that's true also for the cofinite metric). Therefore if your argument were true, $\mathbb R$ under the cocountable topology would have to be compact as well.

Now consider the open cover $\mathcal C=\{U_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ with $U_n=(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb N)\cup\{n\}$. For every finite subcover $\mathcal F\subset\mathcal C$, there is some $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $U_k\notin\mathcal F$. But then $k$ is not covered by $\mathcal F$. Therefore $\mathbb R$ under the cocountable topology is *not* compact, in contradiction to what your argument would say if it were valid.

Therefore your argument is not valid.

Comment: Why did you write $U_n=(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb N)\cup\{n\}$ instead of just $U_n=(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb N)$?

Comment: @Holmes: Because otherwise the natural numbers would not be covered. Each set covers the non-natural numbers and exactly one natural number, and there's a set for each natural number, therefore the collection covers all numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To see why it is compact, let $\{U_a\}_{a \in A}$, $A$ some arbitrary indexing set, be an open cover for $\Bbb{R}$. Then for some $b \in A$, we have for each $x \in \Bbb{R} \setminus U_b$ an open set $U_x$ containing $x$, then

$$\Bbb{R} \subset U_b \cup \bigcup_{x \in \Bbb{R} \setminus U_b}U_x$$

which is finite as $\Bbb{R} \setminus U_b$ is finite.